# Is there any one work with circulargauge from syncfusion on?

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am working with circulargauge from syncfusion on Angular but I couldn't display value on it. How can I bind value on this gauge?

HTML:

```
<div nz-col nzSpan="8">
      <ejs-circulargauge #customization1='' width="180" height="200" [axes]="axes1"  
       id='customization-container1' >
      </ejs-circulargauge>
</div>
```

Ts:

```
public axes1: object = [{
    annotations: [{
        content: '<div style="color:#666666;font-size:35px;">50.5GB</div>',
        angle: 180, radius: '0%', zIndex: '1'
    }, {
        content: '<div style="color:black;font-size:15px;">Used</div>',
        angle: 180, radius: '25%', zIndex: '1',
        textStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            color: '#9E9E9E',
            fontStyle: 'Bold',
            fontWeight: 'Regular',
            size: '14px'
        }
    }],
    lineStyle: { width: 0 },
    startAngle: 180, endAngle: 180,
    radius: '97%',
    labelStyle: { font: { size: '0px' } },
    majorTicks: { width: 0 },
    minorTicks: { height: 0 },
    minimum: 0, maximum: 100,
    ranges: [{
        start: 0, end: 100,
        radius: '97%', startWidth: 20,
        endWidth: 20, color: '#E0E0E0'
    }],
    pointers: [{
        type: 'RangeBar',
        value: 70, radius: '97%',
        color: '#003366', animation: { duration: 0 },
        pointerWidth: 20
    }]
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the value of the pointer using the `axes[].pointers[].value` property present in the Circular Gauge widget. Using this property, the pointer value can be changed dynamically in a button click or any other event. The current pointer value can be displayed using the `annotations` in the Circular Gauge widget. Please find the code snippet for changing the pointer value below.

**Code Snippet:**

```
[app.component.html]
<button id="currentValue1" (click)="onClickAdd()"> Value Added
</button>
<ejs-circulargauge #customization1></ejs-circulargauge>

[app.component.ts]
@ViewChild('customization1')
 public gaugeObj: CircularGaugeComponent; // created instance for the gauge.
// Bind the pointer value in the below method <br/>
onClickAdd() { 
    this.gaugeObj.axes[0].pointers[0].value = this.gaugeObj.axes[0].pointers[0].value + 10;
    let pointerValue: number = this.gaugeObj.axes[0].pointers[0].value;
    this.gaugeObj.setAnnotationValue(0, 0, '<div style="color:#666666;font-size:35px;">' + pointerValue + 'GB' + '</div>');

  }
```

We have created a sample and it can be found from the below StackBlitz link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syncfusion-circular-gauge-ypj3oz?file=app.component.ts